# How does this easy transformation in logistic regression work?

Tags: statistics, logarithms, exponential-function, logistic-regression

I know it's easy, but unfortunately not for me:/

I have:

$$ p(X) = \frac{e^{\beta_0+\beta_1X}}{1+e^{\beta_0+\beta_1X}} $$

and this turns out to be:

$$\frac{p(X)}{1-p(X)} = e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1X}
$$

How does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this equation :
$$x=\frac{y}{1+y} \tag 1$$
I suppose that it is easy for you to solve it for $y$. You get :
$$y=\frac{x}{1-x} \tag 2$$
Let $x=p(X)$ and $y=e^{\beta_0+\beta_1X}$
$$ p(X) = \frac{e^{\beta_0+\beta_1X}}{1+e^{\beta_0+\beta_1X}}=x=\frac{y}{1+y}$$
This is the above equation $(1)$ which solution is  above $(2)$ :
$$y=\frac{x}{1-x}=e^{\beta_0+\beta_1X}=\frac{p(X)}{1-p(X)}$$

Comment: Thank you very very much;)!! I need to confess that I just get to $$y = \frac{-x}{x-1}$$ in (1). Is this the same as? Sorry...:/ $$y = \frac{x}{1-x}$$

Comment: That is OK. : $\frac{-x}{x-1}=\frac{-x}{-(1-x)}=\frac{x}{1-x}$ Baby school ?

Comment: absolutely babyschool;) Thanks anyways!